# How to convert word document to PDF in SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-addin, custom-javascript

Is it possible to convert a word document to PDF on SharePoint 2016 using custom code such as JavaScript ? I have heard of Word Automation Services but I am looking for custom code solutions that would run on a click of a button. Example, Click on a button and the word document automatically is converted to a PDF document.

Comment: WAS does this -- requires custom code, but it does require a full trust solution and you would need to create your own UI, but you can do 'button click' conversions. Example solution at https://github.com/Nauplius/WAS.

Comment: If developing this yourself is not an option then there are off-the shelf solutions available to do exactly this, and much more, see https://www.muhimbi.com/Products/PDF-Converter-for-SharePoint/summary.aspx. Disclaimer, I worked on this product so consider me biased.